# Display id demo using name doesn't work when I use getElementsbyName

Tags: javascript

I want to display the **ID** `demo` using `name` but it doesn't work when I use `getElementsbyName`.

```
<input type="" id="demo" value="" class="form-control TimeInfo" name="txtTimeInfo[]" readonly />

<script>
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").value= d;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? There's no `getElementsByName` method used in your code ..?

Comment: As it is already mentioned in the answer by **BRK** that for the `input` control you have to use the property `value` and if you have any static controls like `label, div, span and etc` you can use the `innerHTML` to set the value in them and for the `getElementsbyName` it should be used when you have multiple controls with same name attribute as `name="txtTimeInfo[]"` which in return will give you a list(array) of controls that contains the name property which you can access by index and use them.

Answer (score 1):

For input control you need to set `value` not `innerHTML`

```js
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").value = d;
```

```html
<input type="" id="demo" value="" class="form-control TimeInfo" name="txtTimeInfo[]" readonly />
```

Comment: OP has apparently edited his question to use `value`... it's confusing...